# SQL Server Migration Assistant Identity Generation

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, migration, sql-server-migration-assi

I am using SSMA for migration from Oracle to SQL Server 2012. I want to migrate primary keys from Oracle as identity and primary key on SQL Server 2012. SSMA wants me to map every single primary key on source db with corresponding sequence but I have over 200 tables so is there a shortcut for this operation? I don't care about sequence values. Is there a way to say SSMA "Generate new sequence for every primary key and map them to identity(1,1)" ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that newer versions of SSMA are not using SQL Server identity columns by default. But looking into [the migration guide from Oracle to SQL Server 2012](http://download.microsoft.com/download/E/C/9/EC9523C2-D361-47BB-960A-AC2863DEB443/SQL_Server_2012_Guide_to_Migrating_from_Oracle_to_SQL_Server_2012.pdf) section "Migrating Oracle Sequences" I suspect that changing Tools > Project Settings > General > Conversion > Sequence Conversion to "Using column identity" should suffice.

PS: I didn't try it on newer SSMA versions, judging based on the guide only.